# Hide wordpress field if data is empty in post!

Tags: php, posts, customization, code

I'm using this code to show my field:

```
<?php echo '@ ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Author:', true); ?>
```

When I add a field in my posts it shows it with no problem but for posts that I don't add any fields it shows "@".
What I can do to not show anything if field is empty in a post?
Examples: [field with data](https://rule34cartoon.com/d-va-sex-overwatch-6/) - [field with no data](https://rule34cartoon.com/manami-katsura-sex-school-days/) [Warning: Both links are NSFW +18]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a simple check, to see if you have this meta

```
$author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Author:', true);

if ( $author ) :
    echo '@ ' . $author;
endif;
```